# Missing files from mysql odbc driver installer

Tags: mysql, windows, odbc

I'm trying to install the latest (5.2.7) version of the MySQL ODBC driver on Windows server 2008 R2, but when starting the installation, I get the following error:

[image: ODBC Insatllation Error]

MySQL Workbench installs fine and works well. I just need to connect to MySQL from my windows desktop application to import some data.

Note. I've installed Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable and rebooted, the error remains.

Comment: You need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ <latest/2010> Redistributable Package (select the appropriate one for your OS architecture (64 bit or 32 bit), then re-attempt installing the MySQL ODBC connector, and things should work smoothly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this I have done before posting, but to no avail. I'm thinking a reboot might be in order, but it's on a live production environment. Will schedule a restart and report back here.

Comment: Nope, no luck, same error after installing MVC++ redistributable and rebooting. Is ODBC still supported by MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old, but for those searching, as me recently ;) Part of [documentation](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-odbc-en.pdf) section 4.1:

> Make sure the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio is installed. 
>   • Connector/ODBC 8.0.14 or higher: VC++ Runtime 2015 or VC++ Runtime 2017 
>   • Connector/ODBC 8.0.11 to 8.0.13: VC++ Runtime 2015 
>   • Connector/ODBC 5.3: VC++ Runtime 2013 
>  
>   Use the version of the package that matches the system type of your Connector/ODBC driver: use the
>   64-bit version (marked by “x64” in the package's title and filename) if you are running a 64-bit driver, and
>   use the 32-bit version (marked by “x86” in the package's title and filename) if you are running a 32-bit
>   driver.